# Почему не прибавляет к числу взятому из cookie?

Tags: javascript

Есть код собирающий статистику, при первом визите записывает в куку number_visit номер 1 визита, при втором посещении человека пытаюсь взять из куки number_visit номер визита т.е. 1 и прибавить к ней +1, но получается почему-то 11!

**Почему так происходит?**

код такой:

```
number_visit = getCookie(NUMBER_VISIT_COOKIE)+1; // прибавляем +1 визит
```

Comment: потому что в куках хранится строка

Comment: @Grundy чет я не подумал об этом

Answer (score 1):

В куках хранятся **только** строки, поэтому при получении значения `getCookie(UCRM_NUMBER_VISIT_COOKIE)` это строка и при сложении операнды приводятся в этом случае к строкам.

Для решения проблемы нужно привести строку в число: например используя унарный `+`

```
number_visit = (+getCookie(NUMBER_VISIT_COOKIE))+1
```